# Failed to start permit user sessions

Tags: boot, boot-issues, user

When my RP boots, I get several errors about some services failing.
Most notably 'permit user sessions'.

[image]

Which means I can not log in to the device, and I can not make changes to it.

I can of course remove the SD card and change the contents that way.

I would prefer solutions that do not involve 'try writing the image to the SD card again.' I have tried that several times (see other questions by me). So far I have not yet found a way to keep my raspberry pi running more than 1 day.

Questions:

1. What is happening?
2. Why is this happening?
3. How do I fix it?
4. Is there a release of Raspbian that is at least more stable. This thing feels buggy. Like I mentioned, I have not yet gotten this to work more than 1 day in a row.

Comment: Buy a new quality SD Card and make sure to power it down properly. I have several Pi that run for months without issues, but once a SD Card becomes flaky nothing will help.

Comment: Why do you assume it's the SD card? How did you pinpoint that as the root cause? Not making any accusations. Just trying to learn.

Comment: I make no assumptions - you have provided no information to draw any conclusions but the error messages indicate OS problems. My (few) similar experiences were flaky SD Cards.

Comment: There might be useful information in the system log as to what the errors are. If you haven't looked at it, that would be a great place to start. If you can't login, you'll have to sort out how to look at the /var/log files from another system. Difficult from Windows, easier from Linux, and I assume Mac (altho I am Mac illiterate by choice, so can't say for sure)

Comment: Which files from /var/log would you like to see?

Comment: What does it mean: "*I have not yet gotten this to work more than 1 day in a row*". Does it mean if you boot a fresh flashed image after 12 hours it works but if you boot it after 25 hours it fails? Please address me with @Ingo otherwise I won't see your reply. And please don't answer in a comment. Instead edit your question to clarify.